# `self` is a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure

Tags: rust, esp32, esp-idf-sys

I'm trying to create a struct that enables a pin and then disables it after a period of time. I'm running into an issue of ownership and I'm not quite sure how to resolve it.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```rust
pub trait PumpPin {
    fn enable(self);
    fn disable(self);
}

impl PumpPin for Gpio4<Output> {
    fn enable(mut self: Gpio4<Output>) {
        self.set_high().unwrap();
    }

    fn disable(mut self: Gpio4<Output>) {
        self.set_low().unwrap();
    }
}

pub struct PumpManager<T: PumpPin + std::marker::Send + 'static + std::marker::Sync> {
    pin: T,
}

impl<T: PumpPin + std::marker::Send + 'static + std::marker::Sync> PumpManager<T> {
    pub fn new(pin: T) -> PumpManager<T> {
        PumpManager { pin }
    }

    pub fn run_pump(self, time: u64) -> Result<(), EspError> {
        self.pin.enable();

        // Configure the timer to disable the pin
        let once_timer = EspTimerService::new()
            .unwrap()
            .timer(move || self.pin.disable());

        //actually set a time for the timer
        once_timer.unwrap().after(Duration::from_secs(time))
    }
}
```

My goal was to encapsulate all of the logic that handles the timing of the pump.

The error I get below is at `self.pin.disable()`

```
cannot move out of `self.pin`, as `self` is a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
move occurs because `self.pin` has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I thought the ownership of pin would belong to `PumpManager` itself but it actually belongs to whatever function is calling it. Is there a way I can refactor this to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is almost correct: `pin` is owned by `PumpManager`, but `PumpManager` is owned by `run_pump()` because that method takes ownership via `self`.

There is a confluence of expectations here: `PumpPin::disable()` takes ownership via `self`, but `esp_idf_svc::timer::EspTimerService::timer()` expects a `FnMut()`, that is, it expects a closure that can be called multiple times (think of a periodic timer). But we can't move ownership of `self.pin` into the closure, move `pin` out of the closure via `pin.disable()`, and call the closure again - because `pin` would be gone by then. This is why the requirement for `FnMut` is not satisfied.

*Essentially, your problem is that `EspTimerService::timer()` enforces a closure that can be called from periodic timers, while `PumpPin::disable()` enforces that it can be called only exactly once, yet is called from what could be a periodic timer; one might say the `esp_idf_svc`-API is poorly designed, but the contradiction is what it is.*

If you can change `PumpPin::disable()` to not take ownership (but e.g. `&mut self`), your closure can become a `FnMut` as is.

If you can't change `PumpPin::disable()`, you may move `self.pin` into an `Option` and `.take()` the `pin` out of that `Option` inside the closure. The call to `.take()` will give you an owned value on the first call (the only time the timer executes), and would return `None` thereafter if the timer fired multiple times (which does not happen, but it would be correct as far as the compiler is concerned). For instance:

```rust
// Some FnMut, like the timer-callback
fn take<T: FnMut()>(_: T) {}

struct Foo {
    bar: String,
}

impl Foo {
    fn do_take(self) {
        // Destructure `self`, put `bar` into an `Option`
        let mut s = Some(self.bar);
        
        take(move || {
            // Move out of the `Option`.
            // If this closure was executed before (as a `FnMut` could),
            // this would not execute, because we leave a `None`
            if let Some(s) = s.take() {
                // We now own `s` and can call methods that take `self`.
                // But this path can only execute once, while the closure
                // as a whole can execute multiple times.
                println!("{s}");
            }
        })
    }
}
```